# Get doctrine.orm.entity_manager is null in phpunit test

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I'm running phpunit tests on some classes and I get this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get() on null in src/MyApp/MyBundle/Classes/Action/CopyList.php on line 415
```

At that line is

```
$em = $dic->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

from

```
namespace MyApp\MyBundle\Classes\Action;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session;   
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag;

class CopyList extends Action {

public function __clone($task) {
    $dic = Environment::getInstance()->getContainer();

    $em = $dic->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

    $list = $em->getRepository('MyAppMyBundle:CopyList')->findByName($task);

    if (!$list) {
        $list = new CopyList();
        $em->persist($list);
        $em->flush();
    }  
}
```

which is being called from the line

```
$clone = clone $container;
```

in

```
namespace tests\src\MyApp\MyBundle\Classes;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

abstract class TaskContextContainerTestCase extends TestCase {

public function testCloning() {
    $container = $this->createInstance();
    $container->setImmutable(true);

    $this->assertTrue($container->isImmutable());

    $clone = clone $container;

    $this->assertNotEquals($container, $clone);
    $this->assertFalse($clone->isImmutable());
}
```

I've tried doing something like

```
protected function getEmMock()
{   
    $emMock  = $this->getMock('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager',
        array('getRepository', 'getClassMetadata', 'persist', 'flush'), array(), '', false);
    $emMock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getRepository')
        ->will($this->returnValue(new FakeRepository()));
    $emMock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getClassMetadata')
        ->will($this->returnValue((object)array('name' => 'aClass')));
    $emMock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('persist')
        ->will($this->returnValue(null));
    $emMock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('flush')
        ->will($this->returnValue(null));
    return $emMock;  // it tooks 13 lines to achieve mock!
 }
```

from [here](https://gist.github.com/wowo/1331789) but I don't think I'm doing it right. For example I have put that code in the `setUp()` function of `TaskContextContainerTestCase`. Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it's not the good solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see is in the line...

```
$em = $dic->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

of your CopyList class. If you want to mock de entity manager. You should be doing a dependency injection.

```
namespace MyApp\MyBundle\Classes\Action;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session;   
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class CopyList extends Action {

   /**
    * @var EntityManager
    */
   private $em;

   public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
       $this->em = $em;
   }

   public function __clone($task) {
      $dic = Environment::getInstance()->getContainer();

      //Where is this $listName coming from? shoudn't be $task?
      $list = $this->em->getRepository('MyAppMyBundle:CopyList')->findByName($listName); 

      if (!$list) {
         $list = new CopyList();
         $em->persist($list);
         $em->flush();
      } 
   }
}
```

To mock the entity manager use...

```
protected function getEmMock()
{   
    $emMock  = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(array())
        ->getMock;
    $emMock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getRepository')
        ->will($this->returnValue(new FakeRepository()));
    $emMock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getClassMetadata')
        ->will($this->returnValue((object)array('name' => 'aClass')));
    $emMock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('persist')
        ->will($this->returnValue(null));
    $emMock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('flush')
        ->will($this->returnValue(null));
    return $emMock;  // it tooks 13 lines to achieve mock!
 }
```

I will rebuild the test building a new instance

```
$copyList = new CopyList($this->getEmMock());
```

Then you will have your instance with the mock entity manager

have a look on this tuts, they help me a lot...

https://jtreminio.com/2013/03/unit-testing-tutorial-introduction-to-phpunit/

Comment: Related to this, the line `$this->em->getRepository('MyAppMyBundle:CopyList')` is now giving me `Call to a member function getRepository() on null`. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: So where do I put/call the getEmMock? I mean, I just understand how that function fits with the test class and class being tested.

Comment: yeah I've read through his tutorials a few times, thanks for your time, I'll try to make it work, if not I'll just post another question